# VBA Copy column name from one sheet to all other sheets

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I'm stuck on a code with

> Runtime Error 424, Object required

The code is basically copying a column from the first sheet name "Generate" and transpose the copied column to a header row on all other active sheets except "Generate".

Could anyone help me to fix the error?

```
Sub Test()   
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "Generate" Then
  Worksheets("Generate").Range("B2:B42").Copy
  ActiveWorksheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,  0).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you putting a 'header row' into `ActiveWorksheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,  0)` ?

Comment: Change ActiveWorksheet.Range( to ws.Range(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try collecting the column header labels into an array first.

```
sub test()
    dim hdrs as variant, w as long

    with worksheets(1)
        hdrs = application.transpose(.range(.cells(2, "B"), .cells(.rows.count, "B").end(xlup)).value2)
    end with

    for w=2 to worksheets.count
        with worksheets(w)
            .cells(1, "A").resize(1, ubound(hdrs)) = hdrs
            '.cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).offset(1, 0).resize(1, ubound(hdrs)) = hdrs
        end with
    next w
end sub

'alternate by worksheet name

sub test()
    dim hdrs as variant, w as long

    with worksheets("Generate")
        hdrs = application.transpose(.range(.cells(2, "B"), .cells(.rows.count, "B").end(xlup)).value2)
    end with

    for w=1 to worksheets.count
        if lcase(worksheets(w).name) <> "generate" then
            with worksheets(w)
                .cells(1, "A").resize(1, ubound(hdrs)) = hdrs
                '.cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).offset(1, 0).resize(1, ubound(hdrs)) = hdrs
            end with
        end if
    next w
end sub
```

Comment: Worksheets("Generate") may or may not be Worksheets(1).  Better to use the OPs structure to loop the sheets

Comment: Yes, I took the OP literally with *'copying a column from the first sheet name "Generate"'*. Her worksheet name variation had no errors I could foresee and could easily be applied here.